# Transições numa página

Tags: javascript, html, transição

boa tarde!
Estou com uma ideia de desenvolver uma página de apresentação e com um botão que na forma padrão redirecionaria para uma outra página, mas, quero deixar essa interação melhor.

Queria saber o que devo usar e qual a estrutura correta para que: Quando o usuário clicasse no botão, ao invez de mudar bruscamente, ocorrer uma animação de SUMIR os elementos da página e surgir os elementos da outra página de maneira animada.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que você pretende, não precisa criar transição entre páginas. Basta utilizar um Carousel pra isso.

O do Bootstrap é muito bom:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Nos sites a seguir, você pode encontrar exemplos adequados para adicionar transições entre páginas html usando css3 com bibliotecas como jquery. Eles incluem demonstrações ao vivo e código completo:

http://smashinghub.com/15-page-transitions-effects-tutorials-in-css3-and-jquery.htm

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796315/how-i-can-add-transitions-between-two-html-pages)